# Jboss fuse with EAP container

Tags: jbossfuse

I am new to Jboss fuse. I went through several tuitorials regarding fuse. 
JBoss Fuse combines several technologies like Apache Camel, Apache CXF, Apache ActiveMQ, Apache Karaf and Fabric8 
in a single integrated distribution.

I have downloaded the installer from jboss site and installed in to jboss-EAP 6.4 . I checked the standalone.xml and didnt find any configuration regarding
Apache ActiveMQ, Apache Karaf and Fabric8.
My doubt is without these configurations how fuse will support messaging service and osgi ?
I am trying to use fuse in jboss-EAP 6.4 server as osgi.(fuse+server+osgi)
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss EAP is for your web application. JBoss Fuse is the middleware and ActiveMQ is the message broker.

There is no ActiveMq in EAP as it's your Application Server where you run your web applications. You can use ActiveMq in EAP but it's not designed for that. However you can find an ActiveMq configuration in JBoss Fuse where is more suitable to use broker. JBoss Fuse isn't something you can use inside the EAP but it's a separate application that you can use WITH the EAP. So your question probably is "how to connect JBoss Fuse  and JBoss EAP?" If so, then you can achieve that by using HTTP queries from EAP to Fuse for example.

About your doubt JBoss Fuse supports OSGi and by using Apache Camel inside your OSGi bundles you can use the ActiveMq component to connect and send/receive AMQ messages.

If you tell us more what you are trying to achieve using the JBoss ESB Stack probably we can help you more.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks Angelo. I am trying to integrate fuse features in jboss server, but instead of karaf container I want to use jboss server as container and felix as osgi.

Comment: Felix, Karaf and Fuse are OSGi containers. They contains and runs OSGi bundles (jar files). The "features" in fuse is a xml document describing groups of bundles/jars. The idea is to allow to deploy them at once or in logical groups into the container - fuse, karaf or felix. JBoss application server (AS or EAP) is used to run just web applications (WAR files).

Comment: So jboss application server with karaf integration is not possible ?

Comment: They are different and separate applications. But to make an integration is possible with both of them using Apache Camel which is very good framework that implements many enterprise integration patterns. http://blog.christianposta.com/camel-on-jboss-eap-with-custom-modules/